# I need steps how to convert dita to word using DITA OT plugin named com.elovirta.ooxml in oxygen

Tags: docx, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

I need steps to convert DITA to word process in oxygen by using the plugin name called **com.elovirta.ooxml** using [this](https://github.com/jelovirt/com.elovirta.ooxml) link,

Input Dita xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="d63e3" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="Student_Notebook">
  <title outputclass="Title">Student Notebook</title>
  <body>
    <section outputclass="Handout"><title>Labs Student Notebook
        1</title><p outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Module 1</p><p
        outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Literacy Labs</p><p outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Student
        Notebook</p><p outputclass="SC_P_Medium">________________ _______________ _______________
        _______________ </p></section>
  </body>
</topic>
```

I tried through DITA-OT 2.1.0, After installation of three plugins com.elovirta.ooxml, org.dita.base, org.dita.pdf2 in dita ot because those three plugins depended on each other so i installed three plugins. In **com.elovirta.ooxml** plugin.xml code like this mentioned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin id="com.elovirta.ooxml">
  <require plugin="org.dita.pdf2"/>
  <feature extension="dita.conductor.transtype.check" value="docx"/>
  <feature extension="dita.transtype.print" value="docx"/>
  <feature extension="dita.conductor.target.relative" file="integrator.xml"/>
</plugin>
```

So I have installed three plugins. After that I have runned the command in command prompt like this:

```
C:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.1.0-dita2word>ant -f integrator.xml

Buildfile: C:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.1.0-dita2word\integrator.xml

strict:

integrate:
      [jar] Building jar: C:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.1.0-dita2word\lib\dost-configuration.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

After that

I have done this process in Oxygen:

- In transformation Scenario, I have selected DITA OT Transformation,

  transformation type I have selected,

  and I didn't changed any parameters

  3 points shown in below screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYV1U.png)

By clicking **ok** button I have created scenario after transformation running I am getting this Error:

```
Description: [DOTJ025E] The input to the "topic merge" transform process could not be found. Correct any earlier transform errors and try the build again, or see the DITA-OT User Guide for additional causes.
```

So I have try to do with dita-ot-2.4.1 newer version after plugin installation, i have run the command :

```
C:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.4.1>ant -f integrator.xml
Buildfile: C:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.4.1\integrator.xml

integrate:

BUILD FAILED
C:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.4.1\integrator.xml:43: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet
        at org.dita.dost.platform.Integrator.<clinit>(Integrator.java:79)
        at org.dita.dost.platform.IntegratorTask.execute(IntegratorTask.java:32)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:854)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
        at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1388)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1337)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1089)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 19 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I am getting this error, so i didn't used the DITA OT newer version.

After doing the process in **git** After this command

```
$ ./dita --input=/E/SampleFile.dita -f docx
```

I am getting the error as:

```
 [pipeline] Error at xsl:element on line 64 of topicmergeImpl.xsl:
 [pipeline]   XTDE0820: Invalid element name. Invalid QName {}
 [pipeline]   in built-in template rule
Error: Failed to run pipeline: Failed to process merged topics: Invalid element name. Invalid QName {}
```

Please provide me suggestion to resolve this error as well as up to dita2word conversion.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Java class missing, probably because you mixed incompatible versions of the toolkit or its plugins.

Because you are on a Windows machine, you need a working command line interface to execute the following commands. I recommend to you to install [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win/), because it ships **Git Bash**, which contains a good command line interface that allows you to execute basic Unix commands like **ls**, **vi** and **curl**.

In **Git Bash,** execute:

1. Open your user home directory.

   ```
   cd ~
   ```
2. Create a **temp** directory.

   ```
   mkdir temp
   ```
3. Go to the **temp** directory.

   ```
   cd temp
   ```
4. Download the latest DITA-OT.

   ```
   curl -LO https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/releases/download/2.4.1/dita-ot-2.4.1.zip
   ```
5. Unzip the OT.

   ```
   unzip dita-ot-2.4.1.zip
   ```
6. Goto the **bin** directory.

   ```
   cd dita-ot-2.4.1/bin/
   ```
7. Install the **com.elovirta.ooxml** plugin.

   ```
   ./dita --install https://github.com/jelovirt/com.elovirta.ooxml/archive/master.zip
   ```
8. Generate a docx rom the DITA-OT docs.

   ```
   ./dita --input ../docsrc/userguide-book.ditamap -f docx
   ```

Comment: 'input' format we can add like this?

    ./dita --E:/Batch_4.dita ../docsrc/userguide-book.ditamap -f docx

Is it correct way?

Comment: No, you can find the parameter reference in the docs:
http://www.dita-ot.org/2.4/user-guide/build-using-dita-command.html

Comment: Your answer was partially working for me but I am getting same error by using DITA OT 2.1.0 If possible please help me to resolve that error which is edited in Question

Comment: This site is not free coding service, but based on error message, you have some kind of error in content (element name).

Comment: Hi @Stefan Eike "Dita to word" is it possible with Dita OT 1.8.5?

Comment: Hi @G.VinodKumar, maybe an older version. But OT 1.8.5 is not supported anymore (EOL) and the plugin is developed for the latest DITA-OT version. Even when you still use DITA-OT 1.8.5 in a production environment, you should setup a second DITA-OT 2.4.2 with the com.elovirta.ooxml plugin for DITA2Word conversion. This will surely make your life easier and give you better results.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Stefan Eike

Comment: @Stefan Eike using DITA-OT 1.8.5 this plugin working by doing some changes in XSL for dita file without images but with images its not working please give me any suggestion on this.

Comment: Hi, @Stefan Eike by following your given steps I am getting .docm output not the .docx output for the .docx output what I have to do.

Comment: Give me suggestion on this.

Comment: The plugin always outputs a docm file, which is a docx file with macros. Feel free to open the file and save it as a docx.

Comment: By changing plugin code, Is it possible to get the output as docx? because by running the transform itself i want output as a docx! can you suggest me